# initWithFrame - trying to swap with initWithStyle - Errors occuring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a piece of code using an old depreciated method;

```
cell1 = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:kLastCellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

I tried simply replacing the initWithFrame part to initWithStyle

```
cell1 = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:kLastCellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

However this does not work, and gives a new error

"no viable conversion from 'const CGRect' to 'UITableViewCellStyle' aka 'int'"

I wonder if anyone could help me replace the code line so it fit the new OS without error.

Kind regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ios6 you dont pass a rectangle but a style.

a Style is no rect but a uitableviewcellstyle enum value

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
} UITableViewCellStyle;
```

use e.g. the default

```
UITableViewCellStyleDefault
```